# Update SQL from PHP form

Tags: php, sql, database

When fetching SQL data "s_name" into PHP form input value, for sql update;

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<form action=\"confirm.php\" method=\"post\" name=\"confirm\">";
  echo "<p>NAME:<input name=\"s_name\" value=".$row['s_name']."></p>";
  echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"button\" value=\"OK\"/>";
  echo "</form>";
}
```

My problem; for example, let "s_name" contains spaces, like "United States",
the value in input get "United States" as value but only show before the first space in the field like "United"

My goal is getting "s_name" into a form's input as value, change it and update database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you end up with `value=United States`.

Put quotes around it:

```
value='".$row['s_name']."'
```

And now you'll end up with `value='United Stated'` which will work.

Alternatively:

```
value=\"".$row['s_name']."\"
```

Always helps to "view source" of your generated HTML, issues like this become pretty apparent once you look at the output.